# How to make complex Prisma Schema from JSON data?

Tags: node.js, express, orm, prisma

I'm very new to Prisma ORM. All the tutorials and articles show the basics of model and relations.
But my use case is different, I want to convert the below JSON to Prisma model.

Think this is an Item model and has a relation with `options` and `additions`. And `options` has relation with `list`.

And what would be the model definition for `image` object in Prisma model.

Thanks in advance.

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"American Classic",
   "image":{
      "title":"Image Title",
      "url":"https://assets.suelo.pl/soup/img/products/burger01.jpg"
   },
   "description":"Beef, Cheese, Potato, Onion, Fries",
   "price":9,
   "options":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Size",
         "list":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Normal - 200g",
               "price":0
            }
         ]
      },      
   ],
   "additions":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Prosciutto",
         "price":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: There's no way to "automatically" convert the JSON into a Prisma schema/model. You'd have to do it manually based on the underlying data stored in the JSON itself and applying standard relational data modeling best practices.

Comment: well, could you please show me how would be the model code only for this field

   "name":"",
   "image":{
      "title":"",
      "url":""
   }

Comment: Sure. Is it mandatory for this `Item` object to _always_ have an `image` or is it optional? Also, I assume there's never going to be more than one `image` for a particular `Item` right?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/TasinIshmam/c95783a19d978eeab68e25d031d6acfe) that provides the schema explains its design. If you're still confused, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a Prisma schema from a JSON, you can utilize this helpful library designed specifically for converting [JSON to Prisma schema](https://github.com/omar-dulaimi/json-to-prisma-schema-convertor). This library aims to approximate the conversion process, but please note that it may not be flawless, and some fine-tuning might be necessary after the generation.